# Link to PDF using iTextSharp

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

There is probably a simple answer to this question but I just can't seem to find a solution.

So I'm currently generating a PDF using iTextSharp and sending this PDF back to the user on form submit. However, instead of sending this PDF in the response stream I'd like to render a link to the file i.e. "Thank you for submitting, click here to download the PDF".

Looked at most iTextSharp questions on Stack but all relate to sending it via teh response stream.

Thanks

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(FormCollection formCollection)
    {

        // Create PDF
        var doc = new Document();
        MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();

        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, memoryStream);

        doc.Open();
        doc.Add(new Paragraph("First Paragraph"));
        doc.Add(new Paragraph("Second Paragraph"));
        doc.Close();

        byte[] docData = memoryStream.GetBuffer(); // get the generated PDF as raw data

        // write the data to response stream and set appropriate headers:

        Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=test.pdf");
        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        Response.BinaryWrite(docData);

        Response.End();

        return View();

    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is totally independent of iTextSharp.

You have to store the created byte array somewhere on your server and create another action to  fetch that generated data later by some kind of an ID and serve it to the user.

You can store in in the filesystem or just in the session or TempData.

```
public ActionResult Index(FormCollection formCollection)
{
    // Create PDF ...
    byte[] docData = memoryStream.GetBuffer(); 
    // create id and store data in Session
    string id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    Session[id] = docData;
    return View("Index", id);
}
```

In the view `Index.cshtml` you set string as the modeltype and generate a donwload link:

```
@model string
@Html.ActionLink("Download pdf", "Download", "Controller", new { id = Model })
```

And your new download action:

```
public ActionResult Download(string id) {
    var docData = (byte[])Session[id];

    if (docData == null) 
      return HttpNotFound();

    // clear data from session
    Session[id] = null;
    // a simpler way of returning binary data with mvc
    return File(docData, "application/pdf", "test.pdf");
}
```

Comment: Getting a few errors with your code - VS doesn't like HttpNotFound() for some reason (using .net 4). Also I have changed NewId() to NewGuid() but had to cast to a string. Any ideas?

Comment: Ok, that were faults of my brain compiler :) I have updated my answer and fixed the bugs. `HttpNotFound` is a method and not a class - just remove the `new`.

Comment: Ah ok - so when it returns the view it actually looks for a view with the name of the Guid, how can I pass this to the view as data? Sorry new to MVC, can you tell?!

Comment: No, the view is called like the action. In your case its called `Index.cshtml`. The model type is string. I have updated my answer. The id is passed as the model: `return View(id)`

Comment: Ok I understand but I only want this link to display once the form is submitted. It's the submitted data that then goes into the pdf and then the link should be displayed. Maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: Yes, it should work like this. User submits form to action Index. Index action generates PDF and id, stores PDF in Session and returns a view wich renders the link containing the id. When the user clicks that link, the Download action is invoked, which checks the id and returns the file from session to the user.

Comment: ok thanks Jan - but when I do this... return View(id) - It looks for a view with the name of the Guid and fails.

Comment: OK, that was my fault - because the model (id) is of type `string`, the `View` overload with one parameter as the viewname was taken. In this case you have to specify the viewname: `return View("Index", id);`